# How do I convert Linux shell script to Windows batch file?

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file

I want to convert this shell script to Windows batch file. How I could do this?

```
  #!/bin/bash

  linkreboot="http://admin:admin123!@192.168.1.1/rebootinfo.cgi"

  # ping google
  ping="ping -c 1 -w 3 -q www.google.ch"

  if $ping | grep -E "min/avg/max/mdev" > /dev/null 
      then
          # ping is ok
          echo 'connection is ok'
      else
          # ping is down, reboot
          /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null $linkreboot
          # if no web reboot is allowed

          echo 'No valid ping, reboot'
  fi
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend you convert it to a powershell script, not a batch file. Batch files are by and large superseded by the superior functionality of powershell, which is much closer to bash (though still not very close).

Comment: For something this simple, batch is more than adequate.

Comment: Or, install [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html), and then you don't need to convert any scripts.

Comment: Question without showing any own effort to solve it

Comment: It is not important to me to convert it to powershell or batch. I just want to run this every 30min in my PC.

Comment: Seriously, I don't know batch nor any other windows based shell. But how hard can it be to implement this in batch...

Comment: It's actually extremely easy, we just frown upon people not trying things themselves before they ask questions. You're looking for a `for /F` loop and the `%errorlevel%` variable if you need a place to start.

Comment: Google for `powershell wget` and add the simple PowerShell script to the taskmanager for running it every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download compiled linux command from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win-bash/files/shell-complete/latest/shell.w32-ix86.zip/download)
then in batch file use that 
in batch file syntax very complex but powershell you can 
for ping in batch file you should use

```
@echo off
Ping www.google.ch -n 1 -w 1000
if errorlevel 1 echo Not connected
```

then use wget command from that like 
in powershell you can use :

```
$server = "www.google.ch"
$linkreboot="http://admin:admin123!@192.168.1.1/rebootinfo.cgi"
$date = Get-Date
if (test-Connection $Server -Count 1 -Quiet ) 
{ write-host "connection is ok"
}
else{
wget $linkreboot
}
else {
write-host "No valid ping, reboot"
```

note: in powershell for run script you should change [execution-policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx)

Comment: Thank you it worked.
why did you add "-w 1000" option?

Comment: dear @sajjad that's for time out first packet of ping usually time out because arp you can remove time out if you do not want

Answer (score 2):

Start a Command Prompt.

Type the `ping` command from the `bash` script and see how it works. If you get stuck, type

```
ping /?
```

When you have got that, type

```
findstr /?
```

to work out an equivalent for `grep` and run

```
ping ... | findstr ...
```

Then disconnect your router from the Internet and see how it changes when the network is down.

Google `wget` and install it. See if you can reboot your router when it is disconnected from the Internet using `wget`.

Use http://ss64.com/nt/ if you get stuck or need examples.